# Unable to get CSS Selector "nth-type" working with WebDriver

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Though have been able to use simple CSS (just including id, name) but "nth-type" gives up.

Here is the test method -

```
public static String GetTextByCSSSelector(IWebDriver webDriver, String cssLocator)
    {
        return webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(cssLocator)).Text;
    }
```

and this is the method call -

```
GetTextByCSSSelector(_webDriver, "css=div#filelist div:nth-child(1)");
```

and this is the exception -

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

I used the locator mentioned above in Selenium IDE and it does highlight the element.
Any guess?

#

On a different note, did you support Selenium Proposal on area51 - 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium
You just need to click Commit button to support site, while having logged using your Google/Yahoo account. 
This proposal is backed by SeleniumHQ and we need more users to commit to it to make it see day of light.

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try div:first-child.

If that works it would imply that you only have CSS2 ability, not CSS3 ability.

Comment: I believe this is correct- looks like CSS3 is not supported natively, and not recommended.

Comment: It depends upon the browser, Selenium should support what the browser supports.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `css=` from selector, and enjoy :)